# Get value from an input when click button in foreach

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<h3>{{ $product->name }}</h3>
<input type="number" class="quantity" />
<button id="btn-buy" class="select-buy">Buy</button>
@endforeach
```

I want to get value of in quantity input field when I click on the Buy button. 
The problem is I can get the value but I don't know how to get it into an foreach loop. 
Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use closest function and then find the text field.

php code

```
@foreach ($products as $product) 
<h3>{{ $product->name }}</h3> 
<div class="row"> 
    <input type="number" class="quantity" /> 
    <button id="btn-buy" class="select-buy">Buy</button> 
</div> 
@endforeach
```

javascript code

```
<script>
$(".select-buy").on('click', function(){
  var val = $this.closest('div').find('.quantity').val();

  alert(val);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prev()` function in jquery

I think this should work

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.select-buy', function() {
        // get previous element value only if it is an input
        var value = $( this ).prev().val();
    });
});
```